# YQL sample query returns max 260 results

Tags: yql

I am following YQL sample query

```
select * from local.search(500) where query="sushi" and location="san francisco, ca"
```

but I get 260 max count instead of 500. I tried also to use limit 500 after 'where' and different keywords, always get maximum 260 results. How do you increase it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying API that the `local.search` table uses ([Yahoo! Local Search Web Service](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/local/V3/localSearch.html)) has restrictions on the number of results returned.

The `results` parameter (the number of results "per page") has a maximum value of 20.

The `start` parameter (the offset at which to start) has a maximum value of `250`.

Since you ask for the first 500 results, YQL makes multiple queries against the Local Search API returning 20 results at a time. Therefore the `start` values are `1`, `21`, `41`, ... `241`.  This brings back 260 results, as you have seen.

Since the YQL query asks for more results, the next `start` value is tried (`261`) which is beyond the allowed range so the underlying service returns an error (with the message "invalid value: start (261) must be between 1 and 250"). If you turn on "diagnostics" in the YQL console, you will see the "Bad Request" being returned.

Nothing you do to the query will bring back more results than the underlying service allows.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, I was missing paging number, so 0++ will work

```
select * from local.search(0,500) where query="sushi" and location="san francisco, ca"
```