# Yahoo Query Language (YQL) in iOS

Tags: ios, json, yql

Is it possible to get ALL results in a SELECT statement using the YQL without specifying a where clause.

For example, this block of code will give me stock information for these companies:

```
SELECT * FROM yahoo.finance.quotes WHERE symbol in ('YHOO','AAPL','GOOG','MSFT')
```

But, I am wanting an entire list of every single stock in the Yahoo database (something like this)

```
SELECT * FROM yahoo.finance.quotes
```

Why is this not working? When I do it in YQL console(https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys), it tells me 'Cannot find required keys in where clause; expecting required keys: (symbol)'. Do I always have to use a where clause? If this is the case, then this doesn't seem very useful. If anybody knows a way to get all the stocks without a clause, I'd greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: I don't think YQL allows you to query such large data. According to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400121/yql-sample-query-returns-max-260-results The max number of results is 261.

Comment: I believe you are right Michael. I guess I am going to have to do something a little differently than I originally planned. Thanks for your answer though.